# Wordpress: Delete posts in term when term is deleted

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to delete all posts (of a certain type, in this case "chart") that are associated with a taxonomy term when that term is deleted.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
add_action( 'delete_term', 'remove_site', 10, 3 );

function remove_site( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
  if ($taxonomy != 'sites')
    return false;

  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'chart',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sites',
        'terms'    => $term_id,
      ),
    ),
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );
  }
}
```

remove_site() is being called properly, but $posts is empty. It appears to be the 'tax_query' (because without that, it works and deletes all chart posts), but I can't see what's wrong with tax_query?

Comment: If you change it to just a single level array does it work?

Comment: Nope… The docs (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) show that there is also a "relationship" parameter at the top level Array, and that you can add multiple queries, hence it being a multi-level array.
I tried it anyway and no dice :(
Cheers for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to do similar, I've added the ID field in too - I think it might only match on slug matching unless you specify otherwise?

So...

```
'tax_query' => array( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'sites',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term_id,
                    )),
```

For sanity's sake, I'd just make sure that $term_id is being set, also!

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still no dice… term_id is definitely being set, too

Answer (score 0):

So... the issue I see with this is that 'delete_term' is triggered AFTER it's been deleted.

So, in its after deleted state, the term has NO posts in it, so trying to loop through posts won't work.

In my case, the posts that need deletion would only ever have ONE term attached to it from a custom taxonomy, so I did this:

```
//Remove Client Pages when Client is deleted
add_action( 'delete_term', 'remove_site', 10, 3 ); //run code when a term is deleted

function remove_site( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
  if ($taxonomy != 'client-name') //If term is not in your taxonomy.. don't run code
    return false;

// args to query posts that now have NO taxonomy term
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'client-name',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
        ),
    ),
  );

  $client_pages = get_posts( $args );

  foreach ($client_pages as $client_page) {

        wp_trash_post( $client_page->ID);  // trash all posts that have no term in your taxonomy.
  }
}
```